# web-mgmt not starting in docker

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-datapower

I am new to docker

When I am entering this command **web-mgmt 0 9090** in docker to start DataPower GUI, I am getting this error

20200522T071809.083Z [0x8100051f][mgmt][error] xmlmgr(webgui-manager): tid(111): bytes-scanned '536870912' is not valid. The maximum allowable setting is '430577664

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: My guess would be that you have mapped the ports wrong and something else is firing something against 9090. Did you map `9090:9090` or something else for the portmapping?

Answer (score 1):

The Datapower docker needs minimum of 2 VCPUs. The VM that is hosting the docker container in your case may be of 1 vCPU or something. If you increase the vCPUs, it should just work fine. Thanks!